# Copy Form Fields From One PDF to Another

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a situation where I need to copy all of the form fields from one PDF to another.  The purpose is to automate the overlaying of the fields when small edits are made to the underlying Word pages.

I've been using the trial version of Aspose.Pdf.Kit, and I'm able to copy everything but Radio buttons to a new form.  However Aspose doesn't support copying the radio buttons, which completely nullifies it's usefulness, not to mention their customer support has been subpar.

In any event, I'm looking for some sort of library or plug-in that does support copying all types of form fields.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

~DJ

Comment: Have you looked at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)? I don't know if it does exactly what you need, so posting as comment.

Comment: I've scanned through the website and performed Google searches with iTextSharp as a keyword.  I haven't found a single thing indicating that it can do what I need, so I figured I would see what the community said first before wasting any more time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  No, setField() won't do the trick... madisonw's code will copy the field *values*, but not the fields themselves.

OTOH, it really isn't that hard.

Something like:

```
PdfReader currentReader = new PdfReader( CURRENT_PDF_PATH ); // throws
PdfReader pdfFromWord = new PdfReader( TWEAKED_PDF_FROM_WORD_PATH ); // throws
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper( currentReader , outputFile ); //throws
for( int i = 1; i <= tempalteReader.getNumberOfPages(); ++i) {
  stamper.replacePage( pdfFromWord, i, i );
}

stamper.close(); // throws
```

I'm ignoring a bunch of exceptions, and am writing in Java, but C# should look virtually identical.

Also, this code ignores the case where someone ADDS A PAGE... which would get quite thorny.  Was it added before or after the pages with fields on them?  Did those pages reflow at all, requiring you to move the fields?  At that point you really need a manual process with Acrobat Pro.

Comment: Mark, this is exactly what I needed.  After seeing your code here and reading the code doc, I see why I was confused.  Aspose takes the approach of copying each element from one page to another; this approach replaces the underlying page without moving form fields. Thanks very much!

Comment: This trick will also preserve doc-level information like bookmarks, script, "how to display it on open" settings (viewer preferences), and so forth.  It just swaps out the page content.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Oded, [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) should be able to do the job.  I've used code similar the following snippet and never had problems with any field types.  I'm sure there must have been a radio button in the mix.

```
private void CopyFields(PdfStamper targetFile, PdfReader sourceFile){
{
  foreach (DictionaryEntry de in targetFile.AcroFields.Fields)
  {
    string fieldName = de.Key.ToString();
    target.AcroFields.SetField(fieldName, sourceFile.AcroFields.GetField(fieldName));
  }
}
```

Comment: The SetField function only sets the value of the field, it doesn't actually add a new field object to the pdf file.